# Window always on top over another application in full screen mode in rhel

Tags: qt, rhel

I am having one application that is being displayed in full screen mode in rhel machine
Now I try to invoke kmagnifier and keep it on top of my application but it always goes in background.
Same happens with any other system or user application

Any possible way to fix the position of second application?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot wont be possible as there is simple blank window in full screen mode , the other application goes in background.                    One thing i observed is if i set my display settings as standard then the application doesn't go behind but in case it is compiz , issue persists